# Linear programming for combinatorics/graph theory

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, graph-theory, linear-programming

I just went to a graph theory talk talking about various fractional graph parameters (but focusing on one).  These were defined using linear programming.  A question was asked, "How can we learn more about this technique."  The answer given was, "There is not really a good resource for linear programming in combinatorics/graph theory."  He said Schrijver (spelling?) has a book but you'd have to wade through a lot of stuff to get the stuff that is most important to graph theory/combinatorics.

So, do any of you know of good references that are specifically geared toward graph theory/combinatorics?  It could be a book, chapter of a book, paper, whatever.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can read the chapter on Polyhedral Combinarorics in the [Handbook of combinatorics](http://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Combinatorics-2--Ronald-Graham/dp/026207169X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1320842570&sr=8-1) by Schrijver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like this book [*Understanding and Using Linear Programming*](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/gaertner/lpbook/) by Bernd Gärtner and Jiří Matoušek, and I think most of the material has a combinatorial flavour (published in 2006 - this book is quite recent!). However it is mostly softball stuff (aimed at beginners). If you look at what the coauthor Jiří Matoušek has published you also find a book with the title [*Using the Borsuk-Ulam theorem*](http://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~matousek/akt.html). At first glance this will appear as having nothing to do with linear programming, however there is at least one intersection: The Borsuk Ulam theorem is very general (you can derive Brouwers fixed point theorem from it for example), but you can also derive very simple 'clearly combinatorial' things like the [ham-sandwich theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem). This theorem appears in the 2D variant of the fastest algorithm for 'least absolute deviations', elaborated on in [this article](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~steiger/opt2.ps) by William Steiger, which is almost equivalent to linear programming (I mean 'least absolute deviations' is almost equivalent to linear programming - but I don't know an algorithm beyond 2D for LAD that uses the ham-sandwich theorem effectively - which of course doesn't say much).

Answer (score 2):

Combinatorial Optimization: Theory and Algorithms (Algorithms and Combinatorics) (ISBN-13: 978-3642244872) and Combinatorial Optimization: Polyhedra and Efficiency (Algorithms and Combinatorics) (ISBN-13: 978-3540443896)

The first as general introduction and enough for most cases, the latter as reference material covering basically the whole topic